# Standard deviation and CV

Tags: cross-validation, standard-deviation

I'm using 10-fold CV to compute the classification accuracy of some classifier. I do the CV 10 times with randomly chosen folds.

How do I correctly compute the standard deviation?
Do  I collect all hundred accuracies and then compute the standard deviation or do I average the accuracies over all 10 runs and then take the standard deviation?